# I need to convert a string in android

Tags: android, string, encode

I have a string that looks like this:

```
&lt;div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image
field-label-hidden clearfix"&gt; &lt;div class="field-items"&gt;
&lt;div class="field-item even"&gt; &lt;a
href="/it/news/qualificazioni-fifa-brasile-2014-italia-armenia-alle-2045"&gt;&lt;img
typeof="foaf:Image"
src="http://vivoazzurro.it/files/vivoazzurro.it/styles/news_small/public/media/news/Itali-Armenia%20tv.jpg?itok=23kQIMzS"
width="140" height="105" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class="field field-name-body
field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"&gt;&lt;div
class="field-items"&gt;&lt;div class="field-item even"
property="content:encoded"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Questa sera lo stadio San Paolo
di Napoli ospiterà l'ultima gara di qualificazione ai Mondiali di FIFA
Brasile 2014. Alle 20.45 gli Azzurri, fino a questo momento imbattuti
nel proprio girone, affronteranno l'Armenia (diretta televisiva su
RaiUno).&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

and I have to convert it to a string, but that looks like this:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-hidden clearfix"> <div class="field-items"> <div class="field-item even"> <a href="/it/news/qualificazioni-fifa-brasile-2014-italia-armenia-alle-2045"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vivoazzurro.it/files/vivoazzurro.it/styles/news_small/public/media/news/Itali-Armenia%20tv.jpg?itok=23kQIMzS" width="140" height="105" /></a> </div> </div> </div> <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><p>Questa sera lo stadio San Paolo di Napoli ospiterà l'ultima gara di qualificazione ai Mondiali di FIFA Brasile 2014. Alle 20.45 gli Azzurri, fino a questo momento imbattuti nel proprio girone, affronteranno l'Armenia (diretta televisiva su RaiUno).</p></div></div></div>
```

how can I do?

thanks for the answers

rebus

Comment: it is like encoding "text Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString)" try to use this i am not sure

Comment: simple replace() method would work ,seriously man , WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Html`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class. You can use `Html.fromHtml(myString).toString()` to decode the HTML encoded string.